# Catch all route parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

I have a url such as this: `http://foo.bar/#/some/other/path`

How do I capture "some/other/path" as a route parameter?

I tried this:

```
var App = angular.module("App", [])
  .config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
      .when('/:path', { controller: ListCtrl, templateUrl: 'list.html'})
      .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'})
  });
```

But `:path` is only giving me `some` rather than `some/other/path`

Comment: You'll find catch-all feature as part of upcoming stable version 1.2, or if you don't mind switching to _unstable_ 1.1.3 you can have it right now. Here's [the commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/7eafbb98c64c0dc079d7d3ec589f1270b7f6fea5) (with documentation).

Comment: Thanks! Upgrading to 1.1.3 worked! Is there a way to also do partial matches in a URL? For example, I want to match `.jpg` in `http://foo.bar/#/some/other/path/image.jpg`

Comment: Not sure about that, but here's a [list of links about ongoing discussion on new Angular routing](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Routing-Design-Discussion). Maybe you'll find answer there.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Stewie in the comment above, Angular unstable 1.1.3 now supports catch-all by using an asterisk.

For example:

```
var App = angular.module("App", [])
  .config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
      .when('/*path', { controller: ListCtrl, templateUrl: 'list.html'})
      .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'})
  });
```

Partial string matches—-such as matching for instances of `jpg` in a url—-still don't seem supported.